# Rundeck job executing on a variable host instead of node

Tags: rundeck

Is it possible to execute a rundeck job on some host, which is entered via an option instead of specifying a predefined node? So far I only found that you have to specify a node which represents a known predetermined host.

I have two default servers which can be configured as nodes, but when developing, I would like to create a copy of such a server, but I don't want to add a node for such a machine every time I need one, as it can be deleted after it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need a model source to connect Rundeck to remote nodes, so, in short: you need to add the nodes. Alternatively: you can use rundeck locally and execute commands from script steps that connect to the "non-defined" nodes, like [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Rundeck/comments/1aeqal1/comment/kk9o8dn/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Comment: After researching this a bit more, I came to the conclusion that it is not possible what I want to achieve. According to the docs,what they consider as "dynamic" node creation, this is not very dynamic at all, as as node still has to be known before any jobs run. Its possible to provide nodes via a dynamically called script, but not at the jobs runtime. Its clearly stated in the docs that a node is unrelated to a job. I'm handling this now differently, using an ansible script.